# MWA Setup on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have done the MWA setup in the PC. It's workig fine. Same thing I want to setup in the Windows Mobile 6.5 version. How we can do this. I have done in computer(PC) using this

http://apps2fusion.com/at/43-ss/225-mwa-setup-testing-error-logging-and-debugging

I have done MYMWA.cmd file like this

```
  \Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe -Of -tiny -classpath \Windows\CrEme\lib\AWTclasses.zip;\XONTMWA\lib\j4205328.zip oracle.apps.mwa.awt.client.StartGUI
```

but .cmd/.bat file not supported..

Please anybody tell me is it possible to install in the Windows Mobile 6.5 version?

Comment: You might get a quicker and better answer by contacting the website about how to use their product.

Comment: I asked that palce also.. no answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile does not support cmd/bat files. You need to create a lnk file (a link file). Use your favorite ASCII editor (notepad is fine) and create a new file named mwa-start.lnk. Put only ONE line (do NOT press enter after the line) inside:

```
255#\Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe -Of -tiny -classpath \Windows\CrEme\lib\AWTclasses.zip;\XONTMWA\lib\j4205328.zip oracle.apps.mwa.awt.client.StartGUI
```

Again, NO line end at this line, the file MUST end with the last char and not an CR/LF.

If you have problems editing such a lnk file, name it mwa-start.lnk.txt and later remove the ".txt".

Then copy this lnk file to "\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" dir on the device.

You will then see the new link as a symbol in Start menu of the device.

PS: possibly you need to remove the -tiny flag.